# Field type changes not saving

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column

I have several FLAG fields to stop certain items from repeating. I changed them from Yes/No fields which show as True/False to TEXT fields. I have published the InfoPath forms SEVERAL times, then refreshed and updated SharePoint Designer saved and published the workflows, but when I go back in later, many fields have reverted back to saying "False" and being a YES/NO field. Has anyone else experienced this? Here is an example showing the field in SharePoint is a text field, also in InfoPath, but SD shows YES/NO:

[image]

[image]

I updated and published in Designer, but when I go back a short time later, it has reverted back to "false" meaning it's a Yes/No field again:

[image]

YES/NO field default values from INFOPATH:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only *some* of the fields are changing back to Yes/No, I would guess there is a process or person overwriting your changes.  Are your fields created from Site Columns?  If so, someone may be updating the site column and pushing changes down to your list, overwriting your own changes.

Comment: Well I've been the only person working on this and I'm always sure to open SharePoint then open InfoPath or Designer FROM SharePoint. I do see notifications that some items have changed and I choose to save and publish to accept those changes and still have this issue.

Comment: Wait a minute .... if Designer considered it to be a Yes/No field it would say equals "No" not equals "False" ... are you just checking if a text field equals the word false and incorrectly assuming that means it is a Yes/No field?

Comment: Oh that's something I never noticed before-- if I create the field in SharePoint (not InfoPath) a Yes/No shows values options of: Yes/No,. But in InfoPath, adding  a Yes/No field shows default value options of TRUE/FALSE 1 or 0. At least this gives me something to work with...thank you for pointing that out. I guess it doesn't explain the reverting back to True/False values, but maybe the confusion between the 2 field types whether from SharePoint or InfoPath is messing things up in Designer. This isn't the first anomaly I've come across in InfoPath :) Thank you!

Comment: Agreed on the assessment of InfoPath.  Personally, I chose a long time ago to always build up my "data layer" of sharepoint lists through the SharePoint UI, then build my "business logic" in Designer, and finally build my "UI layer" in InfoPath.  I'm sure InfoPath has improved slightly since I made that choice, but following this process has always treated me right and I never looked back.